# Print all matching JSON dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am currently using the AWS Boto3 to try to get a list of all of my current running EC2 instances. I am at the point where I am able to use describe_instances to list all of my instances, but I am trying to figure out how to pull out all of the instance ID's so I can print them AND use them for another part of the script. Ultimately, I have one script that spins up all of the instance, next I want one that tears them all down.

JSON Tree bellow.

To select a specifc one, I have to do this,

```
instance_id = response['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['InstanceId']
```

But I want to be able to select all instances, regardless of how many instances I have, so trying to do [0][1] etc isn't feasable, so not sure how I would go about saying I want every InstanceId that is in the command.

```
{
    u'Reservations': [
        {
            u'Groups': [

            ],
            u'Instances': [
                {
                    u'AmiLaunchIndex': 0,
                    u'Architecture': 'i386',
                    u'EbsOptimized': False,
                    u'Hypervisor': 'xen',
                    u'InstanceId': 'i-6fb4ad61',
                }
            ],
            u'OwnerId': '',
            u'ReservationId': ''
        },
        {
            u'Groups': [

            ],
            u'Instances': [
                {
                    u'AmiLaunchIndex': 0,
                    u'Architecture': 'i386',
                    u'EbsOptimized': False,
                    u'Hypervisor': 'xen',
                    u'InstanceId': 'i-afe3faa1',
                }
            ],
            u'OwnerId': '',
            u'ReservationId': ''
        }
    ],
    'ResponseMetadata': {
        'HTTPHeaders': {
            'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
            'date': 'Thu, 25Aug201623: 44: 09GMT',
            'server': 'AmazonEC2',
            'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
            'vary': 'Accept-Encoding'
        },
        'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
        'RequestId': ''
    }
}
```

Here is the command I am using to get the instance ID.

```
launch_instance = ec2.create_instances(ImageId="xxxxxx", MinCount=1, MaxCount=1,SecurityGroupIds=["sg-xxxxxxx"],InstanceType='m3.medium', SubnetId='subnet-xxxxx')


response = ec2client.describe_instances(
    InstanceIds=[
        launch_instance[0].id],
)

instance_id = response['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['InstanceId']

print instance_id
```

output is i-6fb4ad61

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
instance_ids = []
for reservations in response['Reservations']:
    for instance in reservations['Instances']:
        instance_ids.append(instance['InstanceId'])
```

Comment: I get this in ipython

'AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append''

Comment: @Mallachar sorry, I've made a typo :( I've updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

You may achieve is via:

```
>>> instance_ids = [instance['InstanceId'] for reservations in response['Reservations'] for instance in reservations['Instances']]
>>> instance_ids
['i-6fb4ad61', 'i-afe3faa1']
```

where your `JSON` structure is saved as `response`

Comment: I get TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Actually, for some reason it prints the same one twice for me

In [25]: print instance_ids
['i-6fb4ad61', 'i-6fb4ad61']

Comment: Sorry! Yes there was one issue with the code. Fixed it. :)